# How to Call Kivy Screen ID from Python File?

Tags: python, kivy, screen

So I have an app in Python with a layout built from a .kv file. I have a screen manager and three screens defined in the Kivy file. What I want to be able to do is have the appropriate screen loaded on app startup if a condition is met. The only piece I can't seem to figure out is how to reference the screen ID from Kivy properly to where Python knows what I'm referring to. In the code below, I usually start with self.root.ids.### and then the id of the widget where ### is. I've tried things like self.root.ids.sm.s1 and such to no avail. Code is below:

**Python**

```
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Builder.load_file(_local_dir + '/kivy.kv')
Window.resizable = 0
Window.size = (500, 700)
Config.write()

# Here are the various classes that make up the layout.
# Some have identical class names in the top of the .kv file to define their properties (color, font size, etc.).
# The functions all run under the start function, which is binded to the start button in the .kv file.


class LogMessage(TextInput):
    pass

class FeatureLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(AmgenizeApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.current_user = os.getlogin()
        self.log_output = f"{date_time} Amgenization started by {self.current_user}...\n"
        self.selected_items = []
        playsound.playsound('open.mp3', False)

    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Kivy**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<FeatureLabel>
    font_size: 14
    halign: "left"
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"

<LogMessage>
    background_color: 1,1,1,0
    halign: "left"
    font_name: 'SEGOEUI'
    font_size:14
    id: log_input
    readonly: True
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "top"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>
    background_color: [0, 0, 1, 1]    # blue colour
    background_down: ''
    background_normal: 'btn_spinner_border.png'
    font_name: 'SEGOEUIB'
    font_size:14
    halign: "center"
    height: 25
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"

<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        background_color: (33/255,98/255,166/255,1)
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 25
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: root.width, root.height
                source:'box_bg.png'

        Image:
            source: 'logo4.png'

        Spinner:
            background_color: (33/255,98/255,230/255,1)
            background_normal: 'btn_spinner_border.png'
            font_name: 'SEGOEUIB'
            font_size:14
            halign: "center"
            height: 25
            id: my_spinner
            on_text: if my_spinner.text == "Select Phase": sm.current = "s0"
            on_text: if my_spinner.text == "Phase 1": sm.current = "s1"
            on_text: if my_spinner.text == "Phase 2": sm.current = "s2"
            on_text: if my_spinner.text == "Phase 3": sm.current = "s3"
            option_cls: Factory.get("MySpinnerOption")
            pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
            size_hint: None, None
            text: 'Select Phase'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: "middle"
            values: ['Phase 1', 'Phase 2', 'Phase 3']
            width: 125

        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                height: 500
                padding: 10
                size_hint_y: None
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#0a1d32')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: root.width, root.height
                ScreenManager:
                    id: sm
                    Screen:
                        id: s0
                        name: "s0"
                        manager: sm
                        Label:
                            color: (1,1,1)
                            font_name: 'SEGOEUI'
                            font_size:14
                            halign: 'left'
                            text: "Click the button above to select a phase. Then select appropriate options, and click start."
                            text_size: self.size
                            valign: 'top'
                    Screen:
                        id: s1
                        name: "s1"
                        manager: sm
                        on_enter: app.phase1()
                        GridLayout:
                            cols:2
                            id: phase_1
                            row_default_height: 30
                            row_force_default: True
                    Screen:
                        id: s2
                        name: "s2"
                        manager: sm
                        on_enter: app.phase2()
                        GridLayout:
                            cols:2
                            id: phase_2
                            row_default_height: 30
                            row_force_default: True
                    Screen:
                        id: s3
                        name: "s3"
                        manager: sm
                        on_enter: app.phase3()
                        GridLayout:
                            cols:2
                            id: phase_3
                            row_default_height: 30
                            row_force_default: True
```

Comment: `self.root.ids.sm` will get you a reference to the `ScreenManager`. Similarly, `self.root.ids.s1` is a reference to `Screen` named `s1`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson so I tried that before, and depending on where I put it in the class it either says self or ids isn't defined. Lines such as self.root.ids.logs.clear_widgets() do work though. I would figure it's the same principle but I assume it also needs something to be called after the ID.

Comment: My suggestions will only work if they are used inside a method of the `MyApp` class.

Comment: @JohnAnderson got it to work. And used Kivy Clock in the __init__ to call the function. Thank you!